# What is the best way of polling at regular intervals a Kafka Consumer while using kafka-python?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, polling, kafka-python

I have multiple Producers which are feeding data into Kafka. I wish to run a Consumer every hour to get all the accumulated data in at once and process it further.

---

The options which I thought of are:

- Use a python thread and use an equivalent of setInterval to call a Consumer
- Setting the **max_poll_interval_ms** variable: (as mentioned in a few other answers). However, the official document states

> This places an upper bound on the amount of time that the consumer can
>   be idle before fetching more records. If poll() is not called before
>   expiration of this timeout, then the consumer is considered failed and
>   the group will rebalance
>    This does not sound like that it's responsible for putting a consumer to sleep and then firing it again.

- Instead of polling every hour, I track the Consumer Offset and poll after 10,000 records have been appended to Kafka

However, I want to manage the same within the Consumer itself. What is the best way of the same
?

Comment: You may wanna check if setting a predefined data volume you're willing to process (via `fetch.min.bytes`) would be a better strategy than waiting a predefined time.

Answer (score 1):

Use Cron or your OS scheduler to call a script every hour.

If you need to wait until 10k records are on the topic to do anything useful, then I'm not entirely sure Kafka is a good fit in that architecture. Plus, the consumer lag would practically, constantly be falling behind

Comment: This requirement was for a specific consumer which is used to process events, zip the same and push to a Cloud Bucket. I didn't want this Consumer Pod to be running continuously to minimise costs which is why I was looking to set the Consumer in a way so it runs intermittently.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the official document for max_poll_interval_ms, it is an maximum interval for which the consumer can be idle. After that the consumer is considered as dead and consumer group rebalance occurs.

This is why I would advise that you shouldn't close consumer after 10k. Even though using offset for polling is a good strategy, there is a problem with that. Every new consumer offset doesn't mean it is a new message. Depending on your auto.offset.reset config you might be having duplicate messages.

To save costs of running pod, I would suggest that you should create a topic with less partitions. This might save you on data transfer + storage cost. Although the instance should be kept running.